# Regexp split by space preserving string in curl braces

Tags: regex, split

I have a string that looks like that

`arg1 {0 1} arg2 {5 87} string {with space} ar3 1`

It is split by space, but string may contain spaces as well, so it causes problems for strings with spaces. I still need to split this string, but I'd like to do not split string contained in curl braces and prefixed by `string` keyword. That means that the string above should be split like that

```
arg1
{0
1}
arg2
{5
87}
string
{with space}
ar3
1
```

Can't implement this, I really need to read a lot about regular expressions. Could you please help me?

Comment: You will probably want to do this in *two passes*. Although it may be possible with a single regex, it would probably make your eyes bleed or your head explode.

Comment: Yeah, regular expressions can do that actually :) Then I would appreciate some solution to split by space preserving any text in curl braces.

Comment: Is there a restriction on what ype of regular expression you can use to do this with? Are you, for example, trying to do this in Perl or with `sed`?

Comment: I'm using QRegExp, it is modeled on Perl's regexp.

Comment: I just realized you're splitting some of the bracketed strings, but not others. What is the rule for splitting/not splitting? Non-numeric characters inside the braces?

Comment: It's in the question - *prefixed by `string` keyword*.

Comment: My mistake. Will alter my answer.

Answer (score 2):

step 1:split with space as usual, get an array

step 2: go through the array, if find `{[a-zA-Z]+`, join the next element with a space, and remove the next element.

then you got what you want. the following awk command shows as an example.

```
echo "arg1 {0 1} arg2 {5 87} string {with space} ar3 1"|awk '{split($0,a); 
for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++){
  if(a[i]~/{[a-zA-Z]+/){a[i]=a[i]" "a[i+1];delete a[i+1];} 
  if(a[i])print a[i];} }'

arg1
{0
1}
arg2
{5
87}
string
{with space}
ar3
1
```

**==update==**

OK, based on your comment, this works too:

step1, find out those strings that you don't want to "split", replace with a special string. and important is saving found strings to another array. The pattern in grep example:

```
echo "arg1 {0 1} arg2 {5 87} string {with space} ar3 1 {abc def} {xyz zyx}"|grep -E -o '\{([a-zA-Z]+\s*)*\}'

        {with space}
        {abc def}
        {xyz zyx}

after replace:xxxxxxxxx as the special string

kent$  echo "arg1 {0 1} arg2 {5 87} string {with space} ar3 1 {abc def} {xyz zyx}"|sed -r 's#\{([a-zA-Z]+\s*)*\}#xxxxxxxxx#g'

arg1 {0 1} arg2 {5 87} string xxxxxxxxx ar3 1 xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx
```

step2, do split

step3, replace the special string back with right index.

Comment: Why to split and then join? This looks like unnecessary operations. Isn't it worth to do not split unnecessary strings instead?

Comment: Thanks, but `\{([a-zA-Z]+\s*)*\}` doesn't work for me. `echo "arg1 {0 1} arg2 {5 87} string {with space} ar3 1 {abc def} {xyz zyx}"|grep -E -o '\{([a-zA-Z]+\s*)*\}'` prints nothing on my PC. Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: is your grep an alias?  try `echo "...."|egrep -o "\{([a-zA-Z]+\s*)*\}"`  is it working?  I tried and it works under Bash and Zsh with GNU grep 2.5.1.

Comment: Anyway, I've already solved the problem using regexp + cycle, but I'd like to split it using regular expressions only. Justin's solutions looks fine, but it doesn't work. http://regexr.com?2unv9

Answer (score 0):

I don't know QRegExp, so I don't know if it has [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) capabilities. If it does, you could try splitting on something like this:

```
(?<!(^|})[^{]*\bstring\s{[^}]*)\s
```

That should split on any whitespace character except those inside a pair of braces immediately preceded by the word `string`. It will ignore the `string` keyword if it's already inside a set of braces.

You can also use a simplified version: `(?<!\bstring\s{[^}]*)\s`, although this will be affected by weird stuff like `foo {string {bar qux}}`.

Comment: QRegExp gives "bad lookahead syntax" error on `?<!`. Documentation says `Both zero-width positive and zero-width negative lookahead assertions (?=pattern) and (?!pattern) are supported with the same syntax as Perl. Perl's lookbehind assertions, "independent" subexpressions and conditional expressions are not supported.`. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Tried this regular expression on regexr, it doesn't seem to work. http://regexr.com?2unv6

Comment: @axe - Regexr uses the JavaScript engine, which doesn't support lookbehinds. Offhand, I don't see a way to make this work without lookbehinds, so if QRegExp doesn't support them I recommend using two passes, as Kent suggested.

Comment: Qt uses engine that doesn't support some lookbehinds, looks like loop is the only way. Thanks.